# powershell aws s3 rest structure

Tags: rest, powershell, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

So I have been trying to browse through the AWS documentation for S3 API and the cmdlets.

What I cant figure out how to access information via REST API in powershell.

I know how to do the rest calls, but I do not understand how to create the particular headers required for the AWS rest calls. I just want to do simple GET calls.

I know the Headers require:

```
 Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
 Host: s3-ch1.example.com
 X-Amz-Content-Sha256: abc123xyzetc...
 X-Amz-Date: 20170103T211222Z
 Authorization: .......
```

I can do it on rest clients, but I do not understand HOW those rest clients are formatting X-Amz-Content-Sha256, X-Amz-Date, and Authorization, and more importantly how I do the same in PowerShell.

its ironic since the actual AWStool cmdlet dont provide the things i need to get the data i want.. so I have to still resort to the REST API, but figuring that is hard in itself.

Comment: AWS has documentation about [performing V4 Signing](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/sigv4_signing.html), and some [code samples for C# signature generation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/signature-v4-examples.html#signature-v4-examples-dotnet) you can modify for PS. However, _why_ do you want to do all this manually in Powershell instead of using, say the [S3 Powershell cmdlet](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/powershell/latest/userguide/pstools-s3.html) which interacts with the S3 API?

Comment: The problem is I just need to get info on user buckets and policies, but s3 cmdlet always ends up requiring specifying buckets, specifics I don't have. I also need to have it a bit portable, where it will work on powershell in a webclient, so downloading and installing a cmdlet wont do

Comment: @birryree Another reason you might want to do this is if using [VSTS Hosted Agents](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/build/concepts/agents/hosted) which cannot have any custom software installed